# How to find non-orthogonal bases of a data matrix in python?

Tags: python, basis, vector-space

I have a data matrix of size mXn. I want to know how to find a set of **non-orthogonal** vectors of the matrix where each vector is of size mX1 and the number of basis vectors, say k << n, in python.

Comment: So you want to find a basis of the Vec Space spanned by the columns of your matrix, and you want this basis to be non orthogonal ? What is your definition of an orhogonal basis ?

Comment: @smed Orthogonal means the dot product of any vector to any other vector from the set must not be equal to zero.